# how to put new line or format in send_mail's plain text in django?

Tags: python, django, sendmail

how can I put a new line or format in the send_mail's plain message in django?

i try this one but it wont work:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Title!', '<h1>message : message here</h1> <br> message : message', 'myemail@sample.com', ['toemail@sample.com'])
```

do anyone have an idea about my situation? 
thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types

Comment: What do you see as output and what do you __want__ to see as output?

Comment: So, you're sending a plain text message but expecting HTML characters to work? How does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Django's template loader to render a text file as a string to insert into your email, and attache the HTML as the alternative content?

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def send_message(request):
    context = {'foo' : 'bar'}
    text = render_to_string('some-file.txt', context)
    html = render_to_string('some-file.html', context)
    email_msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('An Email', text, from_email,
        ['someone@domain.com'])
    email_msg.attach_alternative(html, 'text/html')
    email_msg.send()
```